# Firebase Firestore set data, update data not working in IOS

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to update values to Firebase firestore server on a 3 second time interval, but values are not updated in Firebase firestore.

I need to update values to Firebase firestore server. My code to update to firestore:

```
var singleTripLocationTimer: Timer?

        if singleTripLocationTimer == nil {
            singleTripLocationTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 3, repeats: true, block: { (timer) in
                if MySocketManager.shared.currentEmitType == .singleTripLocation {
                    self.emitSingleTripLocation()
                }
            })
        }

private func emitSingleTripLocation() {
        
        guard let currentLocation = AppLocationManager.shared.locationManager.location else {
            return
        }
        guard let authId = LocalDB.shared.driverDetails?.id else {
            return
        }
        let heading = AppLocationManager.shared.currentHeading?.trueHeading ?? currentLocation.course
        var jsonObject = [String:Any]()
        jsonObject["lat"] = currentLocation.coordinate.latitude
        jsonObject["lng"] = currentLocation.coordinate.longitude
    
        let requestId = LocalDB.shared.currentTripDetail?.acceptedRequestId ?? ""
        let tripRef = self.requestRef.document("\(requestId)")
        
            tripRef.addSnapshotListener({ snapshot, error in

                var distArr = [[String: Any]]()
                
                jsonObject["success"] = true
                jsonObject["distancee"] = self.getDistanceFrom(distArr)
                
                print("GET DATE",jsonObject)
                if let id = LocalDB.shared.currentTripDetail?.acceptedRequestId {
                    
                    self.requestRef.document(id).setData(jsonObject,merge: true,completion: { error in
                        if error == nil {
                            
                            /* Set driver status as not available */
                            var additionalData = [String: Any]()
                            additionalData["is_available"] = false
                            self.ref.document(authId).updateData(additionalData)
                        } else {
                            print("ERRORR IN TRIP DATA",error)
                        }
                    })
                }
            })
    }
```

The print statement works, but the values are not updated to firestore.

Comment: Are you sure `jsonObject["distancee"]` matches your json?

Comment: Yes, set data works once the app is launched and then it never works until I relaunch the app.

Comment: Why are you adding a realtime snapshot listener every 3 seconds? You should either (a) add one snapshot listener only one time and then perform a data update every 3 seconds using the data that is updated in realtime by this listener; or (b) make a get document request every 3 seconds and update data right after. Option b doesn't look very attractive so I'd opt for the single snapshot listener.